# How to configure Windows Live Writer 2011 to work with Joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla3.0

I am currently trying to configure Joomla 3.3 to work with Live Writer 2011.
I used to work with Joomla and Live Writer in the earlier versions of Joomla (1.5) and at that time there were a couple of alternatives to configure Joomla for Live Writer.
As far as I can see today there is only one option for this.
I am having problems with configuring this properly

If I check the home page of my blog I can see that XMLRPC is enabled

```
<link href="/joomla/index.php/component/xmlrpc/rsd?format=xml" rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" />
  <link href="/joomla/index.php/component/xmlrpc/manifest?format=xml" rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" />
```

Also the System RSD and XMLRPC plugin are enabled, so apparently everything looks normal but I can not configure Live Writer to connect.
Can anybody please tell me what settings I have to use for:
-webaddress of my blog: I have no DNS record and my blog is at http://192.168.1.100/joomla/ If I use that I can not get past that dialog. Instead if I use http://192.168.1.100/joomla/index.php/c ... format=xml then Live Writer is fine and it goes to the next section where it is asking me about
-Type of blog
-Remote posting web address

thanks

Edit: not sure if this helps but this is what RSD tells me

```
<rsd xmlns="http://archipelago.phrasewise.com/rsd" version="1.0">
<service>
<engineName>Joomla!</engineName>
<engineLink>http://www.joomla.org/</engineLink>
<homePageLink>http://192.168.1.100/joomla/</homePageLink>
<apis>
<api name="WordPress" blogID="1" preferred="true" apiLink="http://192.168.1.100/joomla/index.php/component/xmlrpc/service?format=xml"/>
<api name="MovableType" blogID="0" preferred="false" apiLink="http://192.168.1.100/joomla/index.php/component/xmlrpc/service?format=xml"/>
<api name="MetaWeblog" blogID="0" preferred="false" apiLink="http://192.168.1.100/joomla/index.php/component/xmlrpc/service?format=xml"/>
<api name="Blogger" blogID="0" preferred="false"/>
</apis>
</service>
</rsd>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by configuring DNS and reconfiguring Apache to use a virtual host for my website. 
After you do that you need to remove the plugin (XMLRPC for Joomla!3.1.x version 2.0.7) and reinstall and enable System RSD and XMPRPC plugins.